# SoundCloud widget .play() method not working when tab is in the background (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, soundcloud

I am creating a client-side SoundCloud application and I want to be able to play the next SC widget (iframe object) after the previous widget hits the .FINISH event (referred to in their api https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods). When the page is in focus, it works properly and plays the next track; however, when I play a song and go to another tab, the next song doesn't start playing until I focus that tab again. I am using Chrome right now and haven't tried any other web browsers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this happen every single time? Can you share your code?  I have seen this happen with an app i've built, but it only happens around 5-10% of the time.

Comment: Hey Paul. Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the play() on SC.Widget.Events.READY while the page is in an inactive tab. I made my page title change when the event READY is triggered, it worked. The play() did too, but the effect of it was "paused" until that inactive tab became active again. I did more extensive test with play(), setIntervals and song in progress. It was properly fireing on inactive tabs while song was in progress but never on READY events while inactive tabs. Sorry I can't help you with a solution, I haven't found one yet, hopefully this will guide you through one.

```
    var widgetIframe = document.getElementById("YourPlayer"),
widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);

widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
    document.title = "test";
    // widget.play();
});
```

EDIT: I queued a YouTube iframe after a soundcloud iframe with autoplay using YouTube API. It did exactly the same behavior, it will only start playing if the tab is on active. The more I dig the more I belive it is related to iframe and/or how browser works.